# Would a specific question about the evolution of the system to collect Nielsen ratings be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm curious about steps that Nielsen is taking to change the means through which they collect ratings as people start to turn toward other outlets besides television to watch their shows.

My feeling is that such a question would fall under the subheading of "distribution", and is therefore off topic on the site.   Nonetheless, I think ratings are a vital part of television, so I'm wondering if perhaps there's a chance to consider them a byproduct of "production" for the purposes of the faq?

Comment: My first reaction is this is alright. Im on mobile atm so ill respond later with a full post

Comment: The question:http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8758/how-are-the-measurements-used-by-nielsen-evolving-to-meet-new-methods-of-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! SO!

This is actually a good question, I believe.  Asking for clarification and how Nielson ratings work and about their evolution sounds perfectly in the scope.

The distribution clause is more for discouraging questions on *How to obtain movie/tv show X*.  More than the actual distribution of a movie/show.

---

TLDR; Your question is fine to me.

Comment: Cool, I'll put it up later tonight then.